# Editing Oozie Workflow after submitting through Command Line

Tags: r, hadoop, oozie, hue

After running an oozie workflow using the command line I am unable to edit it using the Hue Workflow editor or even find it in the list of workflows.

I have an R script that generates the workflow.xml and job.properties, and will run the commands necessary to run the scripts:

```
workflow.path <- "workflow.xml" # Hard coded for the sake of this example
system2("hadoop", args = c("fs -put -f ", workflow.path, "/User/service/Test/" ))
system("oozie job --oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run")
```

Moving the workflow into HDFS works fine, and I have verified it is a valid workflow using oozie. Running the job also works like a charm, however if I open up Hue, and navigate to the Workflow and find it, I cannot edit it, only rerun it.

Some background on what I am trying to do: We have a large amount of automated workflows and we are always adding more. They all follow the same pattern as well so automating the creation of the coordinator and workflows is simple. Sometimes these workflows have to modified by people and they need to be able use the web interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, only workflows created via the Drag&Drop Editor can be edited.
Workflows submitted via the CLI can only be visualized.

Comment: so there is no way around that? Okay, can you suggest another way to go about this then?